# Increasing network IO on EC2

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, emr

I'm executing a Spark job on EMR. The job is currently being bottlenecked by network (reading data from S3). Looking at metrics in Ganglia, I get a straight line at around 600 MBPs. I'm using i2.8x large instance type which is suppose to give 10Gbps i.e. ~ 1280MBPs. I have verified that enhanced networking is turned on and VirtualizationType is hvm, Am I missing something? Is there any other way to increase network throughput?

Comment: "_Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [sf]._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Networking capacity** of Amazon EC2 instances is based upon **Instance Type**. The larger the instance, the more networking capacity is available. You are using the largest instance type within the i2 family, so that is good.

[Enhanced Networking](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html) lowers network latency and jitter and is available on a limited number of instance types. You are using it, so that is good.

The i2.8xl is listed as having `10Gbps` of network throughput, but this is limited to traffic within the same [Placement Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html). My testing shows that EMR instances are **not** launched within a Placement Group, so they *might not* receive the full network throughput possible.

You could experiment by using more *smaller* instances rather than fewer *large* instances. For example, 2 x `i2.4xlarge` cost the same as 1 x `i2.8xlarge`.

Comment: Thanks John. Do you know if there is any way to launch EMR cluster in a placement group ? Also, I was trying to use s3 transfer acceleration to see if it helps, but it looks like even that is not supported by EMR.

Comment: I could not find an option to define a Placement Group for EMR. [Officially](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html), placement groups just locate instances in the same AZ (as does EMR), but they might offer more benefits in the back-end. [Amazon S3  transfer acceleration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-storage-update-amazon-s3-transfer-acceleration-larger-snowballs-in-more-regions/) is only relevant for uploading files to Amazon S3 from a location distant from the destination bucket. It does not apply *within* a region.

Comment: I have the same issue on EMR.. I'm running with r3.8x (with 10g Enhanced networking) but I see some flat tops in my network that makes me think I'm at 1gbps.

Comment: here is a useful table for comparing network throughput of instances: https://www.ec2instances.info/

Answer (score 1):

The S3->EC2 bandwidth is actually rate limited at 5Gbps (625MB/s) on the largest instance types of each EC2 family, even on instances with Enhanced Networking and a 20Gbps network interface. This has been confirmed by the S3 team, and it matches what I observed in my experiments. Smaller instances get rate limited at lower rates.

S3's time-to-first-byte is about 80-100ms, and after the first byte it is able to deliver data to a single thread at 85MB/s, in theory. However, we've only observed about 60MB/s per thread on average (IIRC). S3 confirmed that this is expected, and slightly higher than what their customers observe. We used an HTTP client that kept connections alive to the S3 endpoint. The main reason small objects yield low throughput is the high time-to-first-byte.

The following is the max bandwidth we've observed (in MB/s) when downloading from S3 using various EC2 instances:

```
Instance  MB/s
C3.2XL    114
C3.4XL    245
C3.8XL    600
C4.L      67
C4.XL     101
C4.2XL    266
C4.4XL    580
C4.8XL    600
I2.8XL    600
M3.XL     117
M3.2XL    117
M4.XL     95
M4.10XL   585
X1.32XL   612
```

We've done the above test with 32MB objects and a thread count between 10-16.

Also,

Network performance quoted on ec2 [instances matrix](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#instance-type-matrix) are benchmarked as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/). This is network bandwidth between Amazon EC2 Linux instances in the same VPC. The one we are observing between s3 and ec2 instances is not what they have promised.

[EC2 Instance Network performance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/) appears to be categorized as:

- Low
- Moderate
- High
- 10 Gigabit
- 20 Gigabit

Determining Network bandwidth on an instance designated Low, Moderate, or High appears to be done on a case-by-case basis.

C3, C4, R3, I2, M4 and D2 instances use Intel® 82599g Virtual Function Interface and provide [Enhanced Networking](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#enhanced-networking) with 10 Gigabit interfaces in the largest instance size.

10 and 20 Gigabit interfaces are only able to achieve that speed when communicating within a common Placement Group, typically in support of HPC. Network traffic outside a placement group is has a max limit of 5 Gbps.

Summary:  Network bandwidth mentioned is between two instances not between s3 and ec2.Even between two instances when they are in same placement group + have support of HPC we can achieve something around 10/20 Gigabit.